# Select2 AngularJS - How do i dynamically add a tag item?

Tags: angularjs, jquery-select2, angular-ui

I have a select2 input box the defined like this:

```
<input id="searchbox" ui-select2="autoCompleteSearch" ng-model="searchedLeafs" style="width:80%;height:36px;" class="searchbox"/>
```

Basically, while the user can type text into the input box (and select from the suggested autocomplete list), i would also would like to enable the user to click on an angular-based button (on the same scope) which "inject" a tag into this input box (instead of the user typing it).

Does anyone can tell me how you can do it property in angularjs?  i know how to do it in the old plain select2, but coulnd't find how can you manually/dynamically add items (key/value) to the list of tags.

if you want to get a simple example, lets say that instead of you typing the tags that you want to associate with stackoverflow question, you would simply click on a link/button which would add it to the list of tags yourself.

Thx

Answer (score 1):

Simply push a new object into the ng-model's array and assuming it's duck-typed to the rest of the objects it should show up fine.